# node-schedule's object handling and calendar architecture

Tags: node.js, express

My goal is to build a calendar in which you can add events on it and when the event's date arrives it executes code.

```
 My plan was using: 
     Mysql database +
     node-schedule (https://github.com/node-schedule/node-schedule) +
     express.js +
     fullcallendar (https://fullcalendar.io/)
```

Everytime the user adds a event on the calendar, it will get saved to the database mysql and then it creates an object (using node-schedule) to be executed on the date the users input.

If the server crashes or needs to be restarted there will be a loop that will read all of the table's date and create an array of objects to be executed.

is this properly designed, memory wise and logically?

if the user has like 1million dates to be executed, there will be 1 million objects within the server's memory and I dont know if this way is the right one.

Answer (score 0):

1. You would probably want to paginate events by dates, e.g. you don't need to load all user event for each request, but just those fitting in the full calendar view, like a month or so.
2. Whe the user changes the dates on the full calendar, you just send an ajax request to the server fetching new data.

This would be a lot more memory effective, as you will never (almost) have 1m events/objects in memory, just the relevant ones.